# Shifting object positions in a list

Tags: c#

I have a big list of players with poolNum and poolStanding.
Upon selection of the poolSize (from a dropdown menu) it has to shift players accordingly.
If the first pool has 2 players and we want it with 6, it takes players from subsequent pools and shifts their poolNum and poolStanding accordingly.
I'm not pasting my code because it has irrelevant information to the problem but I've summarized it below. Please help.
Regards
edit: dropdown menu has options 2-6 only. Players that move from a lower pool to a higher always take the last standings in the upper pool.

```
Rearrange(int poolNum, int poolSize, list<Participants> participantsList)
participantsList
{
player1 | pool 1| standing 1
player2 | pool 1| standing 2

player3 | pool 2| standing 1
player4 | pool 2| standing 2

player5 | pool 3| standing 1
player6 | pool 3| standing 2
player7 | pool 3| standing 3

player8 | pool 4| standing 1
player9 | pool 4| standing 2
player10 | pool 4| standing 3

player11 | pool 5| standing 1
player12 | pool 5| standing 2
player13 | pool 5| standing 3

}
```

We choose to have 6 players in the first pool so we have to take 4 players from the next pools. Pools 2 has only 2 players so we take them and take 2 more from the 3rd pool -> .OrderBy (x => x.poolNum).ThenBy(x=> x.standing).Take(poolSize - poolNum.Players.Count (// so that means we take 4 players because poolSize(6) - poolNum.Players.Count(2) -> the updated list now looks like this ->

```
participantsList
{
player1 | pool 1| standing 1
player2 | pool 1| standing 2
player3 | pool 1| standing 3
player4 | pool 1| standing 4
player5 | pool 1| standing 5
player6 | pool 1| standing 6

player7 | pool 3| standing 3

player8 | pool 4| standing 1
player9 | pool 4| standing 2
player10 | pool 4| standing 3

player11 | pool 5| standing 1
player12 | pool 5| standing 2
player13 | pool 5| standing 3
}
```

How do I shift all the subsequent pools 1 down and the 3rd pool's standings by 2 ?

It has to look like this ->

```
participantsList
{
player1 | pool 1| standing 1
player2 | pool 1| standing 2
player3 | pool 1| standing 3
player4 | pool 1| standing 4
player5 | pool 1| standing 5
player6 | pool 1| standing 6

player7 | pool 2| standing 1

player8 | pool 3| standing 1
player9 | pool 3| standing 2
player10 | pool 3| standing 3

player11 | pool 4| standing 1
player12 | pool 4| standing 2
player13 | pool 4| standing 3
}
```

The function Rearrange receives the ID of the pool which I wish to modify, the SIZE we need it to be and a List that stores all the players from all pools.
Every object has an id (playerN), pool that it belongs to (poolN) and a standing in that pool (standingN).
By moving players up/down I have to modify the other players' poolN and standingN.

Here is MY code below:

```
public void ReorderParticipants(int poolOrder, int poolSize, List<ClubLeagueParticipant> allPlayersFromClubLeague)
{
    int playersInPool = allPlayersFromClubLeague
        .Where(x => x.lp_pool_order == poolOrder)
        .Count();     

    int movingPlayers = poolSize - playersInPool;

    var playersToMoveDown = allPlayersFromClubLeague
        .Where(x => x.lp_pool_order == poolOrder && x.lp_standing > poolSize)
        .ToList();

    var playersToMoveUp = allPlayersFromClubLeague
        .Where(x => x.lp_pool_order > poolOrder)
        .OrderBy(x => x.lp_pool_order)
        .ThenBy(x => x.lp_standing)
        .Take(movingPlayers)
        .ToList();

    var standingsToPush = allPlayersFromClubLeague
        .Where(x => x.lp_pool_order == poolOrder + 1)
        .ToList();

    var standingsToPull = allPlayersFromClubLeague
        .Where(x => x.lp_pool_order > poolOrder)
        .OrderBy(x => x.lp_pool_order)
        .ThenBy(x => x.lp_standing)
        .Take(movingPlayers)
        .ToList();

    if (playersToMoveDown.Count != 0)
    { 
        foreach (var standing in standingsToPush)
        {
            standing.lp_standing += playersToMoveDown.Count;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= playersToMoveDown.Count; i++)
        {
            playersToMoveDown[i].lp_pool_order += 1;
        }
    }

    if (playersToMoveUp.Count != 0)
    { 
        foreach (var standing in standingsToPull)
        {
            standing.lp_standing += playersInPool;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= playersToMoveUp.Count; i++)
        {
            playersToMoveUp[i].lp_pool_order -= 1;
        }               
    }       
}
```

When pushing players down - all is good, when pulling them to upper pools, however, players that are left in a pool that has been extracted from, still have the old standings from before getting players pulled.

Comment: I realise that your code has information not relevant to the question, but it might be worth spending the time to create some code that is relevant to the question.  No-one can answer your question, because the answer will depend on how you are storing this information; for example, is player a class or a name?  Is "pool" a class, does that refer to a "standing" class?

Comment: I am sorry about that. Edited.

Comment: You've got a method entitled Rearrange - let's start with what's in that...

Comment: I've added even more information, I hope it's clear now ? What other information is required - I'll provide.

Comment: please post CODE

Comment: @decataplachat The problem at the minute is that a valid answer to your question would be: participantList.player1.pool1.standing++;  So I've re-arranged the standing.  As I can not see your code, I have no real way to know whether that would work

Comment: Hello, the code is added.

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve your problem, because I don't know enough about the requirements (for example, if you call the function with:

```
ReorderParticipants(1, 6, test);
```

You seem to imply that the Player 7 would be moved to pool 2, but that would imply that by changing the size of pool 1, yoy also change the size of pool 2.

However, there are a couple of logic errors in your code that might set you on yours way:

```
if (playersToMoveUp.Count != 0)
{
    foreach (var p in playersToMoveUp)
    {
        p.lp_pool_order = poolOrder;
    }
}

int tmpPoolSize = playersInPool + 1;
foreach (var standing in standingsToPull)
{
    standing.lp_standing = tmpPoolSize++;
}
```